# Rake Cucumber error: No such file to load -- feedable (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

System:
OS: Linux (Debian)
rails: 3.1.4
ruby: 1.9.3p194
rvm: 1.14.5

cucumber: 1.2.1
cucumber-rails: 1.3.0

I have the following installed, but when I try and run the following in my app's home directory:

rake cucumber --trace

I get the following error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...

No such file to load -- feedable (LoadError)

/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support
/dependencies.rb:306:in `rescue in depend_on'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support
/dependencies.rb:301:in `depend_on'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support
/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/application.rb:15:in `initialize!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/currienet/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/currienet/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/var/www/currienet/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support    /rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin...]
```

I don't know what 'feedable' is or where it's being loaded. Googling the two error messages has yielded no answers.

Comment: are you sure that you aren't using feedable gem ?

Comment: What is the require at /var/www/currienet/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'

Comment: bundle show
Does not list the feedable gem.

The require at line 7 of env.rb is the following line:
    require 'cucumber/rails'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I should run a grep on my app directory for 'feedable' and found that there was left over code from a class I had written and then removed - this was before I was using versioning control. Once I removed the erroneous require, the problem disappeared.

Thank you to those who spent time on considering this.